# SettingsFlayout for Windows 8.0

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I want to implement some settings GUI for a page in my app.

From as I understand, Microsoft suggests using their `SettingsFlayout`, but my app is designed for Win RT tablets and PC-s with Windows 8.0 as minimum OS version. SettingsFlayout is available `only from Win 8.1 above`...

Could someone guide me how can I accomplish this task? Is there another native way to implement settings for a specific page/view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still targeting Windows 8, you can use the [SettingsFlyout](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/SettingsFlyout) from the [Callisto project](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/).

It's also [available on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Callisto).